# How to do word + consecutive/random numbers with iMacros?

Tags: random, macros, imacros

I need to write a name with a random number or a consecutive number house12 house15 or house18 house19....
I do it:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:mForm ATTR=ID:checkoutm CONTENT=house 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:mForm ATTR=ID:checkoutm CONTENT= EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100 + 1); randomNumber;")
```

iMacros writes house but when writes the random number deletes house...

How can I do for iMacros doesn’t delete house? And how can I do you write consecutive number house18, house19, house20....?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code using the toolbar so that we can understand it better.

Comment: I don’t see the toolbar in the mobile :(

Comment: "I don’t see the toolbar in the mobile" @OP, iMacros doesn't work "on Mobile" either, what's the point of checking SOF on a Mobile...? Even if you get some "Solution"/whatever, you won't be able to test it...! => Use a "regular" PC/Laptop...!

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Any solution please?